# passing QDialog a pointer to QObject and then on return being unable to access content of QObject

Tags: c++, qt, access-violation

I have a q_dialog_controller that receives as a parameter a pointer to a q_object.
This q_object is being passed as a pointer so that the fields in the q_object can be populated in the dialog, and then upon return of control via a QObject::connect() action as the result of clicking a submit button, the original window has access to the data.

However, this is not working.

I have inserted sstream interactions to write debug data to an external file and the evidence I have is comparable to the following:

> q_object content prior to dialog call:
>
> -- Data point one: initial value
>
> -- Data point two: initial value
>
> q_object inside connect block in dialog:
>
> -- Data point one: user entered value
>
> -- Data point two: user entered value
>
> q_object closing dialog
> q_object returned from dialog:

This is where the debug file stops as here is when I get an "Access Violation Reading location" error.

This implies to me that the dialog didn't just use the pointer that was passed to it, but rather "claimed ownership". Then when the dialog closed, the calling block of code no longer had access, though it was able to see that the point is not set to nullptr.

```
class q_custom_object: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
QLineEdit* dataPt1;
QLineEdit* dataPt2;

explicit q_custom_object(QWidget* parent = nullptr):
dataPt1(new QLineEdit(this)), 
dataPt2(new QLineEdit(this)){
dataPt1->setText("initial value"); 
dataPt2->setText("initial value");
};

std::string to_string(){ 
return "\n-- Data point one:"+dataPt1->text().toStdString()+
"\n-- Data point two:"+dataPt2->text().toStdString();
 };
}
```

...

```
class q_control_dialog{
public:
    explicit q_control_dialog(q_custom_object* qco= nullptr, QWidget* parent = nullptr; const std::string* debug_filename = nullptr){
QDialog object_control(parent);
object_control.setWindowTitle("Object Interface");
QFormLayout object_form_container(&object_control);
QLabel dp1_label("Data point 3:", parent);
QLabel dp2_label("Data point 2:", parent);
object_form_container.addRow(&dp1_label, qco->dataPt1);
object_form_container.addRow(&dp2_label, qco->dataPt2);
QPushButton submit("Submit", parent);
QPushButton cancel("Cancel", parent);
QHBoxLayout button_layout;
button_layout.addWidget(&submit);
button_layout.addWidget(&cancel);
object_form_container.addRow(&button_layout);

QObject::connect(&submit, &QPushButton::clicked, [this, parent, &object_control,  qco,  debug_filename]() {
std::fstream debug_file;
debug_file.open(*debug_filename, std::ios::app);
debug_file << "\nq_object inside connect block in dialog:";
debug_file << qco->to_string();
debug_file << "\nq_object closing dialog.\n";
debug_file.close();
object_control.close();
});
QObject::connect(&cancel, &QPushButton::clicked, [parent, &object_control, qco]() {
        qco->deleteLater();

        object_control.close();
    });
};
```

...

```
q_window::open_custom_dialog{
q_custom_object* qco = new q_custom_object(this);
debug_file.open(debug_filename, std::ios::app);
debug_file << "In open_custom_dialog prior to calling the q_control_dialog\n";
debug_file << "q_custom_object content data prior to dialog: \n";
debug_file << q_custom_object->to_string();
debug_file.close();
q_control_dialog( qco, this, &debug_filename);

debug_file.open(debug_filename, std::ios::app);
if(qco==nullptr){debug_file<<"\nq_custom_object left not null but returned null"}
debug_file<<"\nq_object returned from dialog:";
debug_file << q_custom_object->to_string();
debug_file.close();
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].